# Core Data Entity Global Data

Tags: macos, core-data

I have a Core Data entity that is used to store earthquake reports. I would like to store a bit of global data to keep track of when the data was last updated.

The date should be a single date common to all entity objects in the store.

Can I use the Entity userInfo for this? I can't determine if this is read-only or if it can be altered at runtime.

Is there a better way? I don't want to store it in UserDefaults because if the sql files are deleted I want the "date updated" data to go away as well.

Answer (score 2):

Persistent stores can have metadata about the store in addition to the actual data. That would be a good place for this. Metadata is part of the `NSPersistentStore`, so you have to reach down into the `NSPersistentContainer` to get it and change it. Something like this

```
guard let persistentStore = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first else {
    return
}
var metadata = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.metadata(for: persistentStore)
metadata["updated"] = Date()
persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.setMetadata(metadata, for: persistentStore)
self.saveContext()
```

The last line is there because metadata doesn't get saved until you save changes, even though it's metadata instead of actual data.

It's best to read the existing metadata first because Core Data puts some of its own metadata in there. You probably wouldn't be able to corrupt that, but make sure by reading it first and leaving the existing values alone.